# make 2-dimension coordinate using mysql select results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question about mysql queries.

I have a table which have data below.

```
From To Weight
--------------
A    B    1
A    C    3
B    C    2
D    E    4
```

And I want to get sql result like below..

```
(?) A   B   C   D   E
----------------------
A   0   1   3   0   0
B   0   0   2   0   0
C   0   0   0   0   0 
D   0   0   0   0   4
E   0   0   0   0   0
```

And what data is in original table is not determined.
How can I acheive this?

Comment: Consider handling such display related requirements in the application code (eg: PHP, C++, Java). SQL is not suitable for dealing with dynamic number of columns (with dynamic names)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Actually I've tried, but size of original data is too big to handle in application code.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the original columns, you can do:

```
select c.col1,
       sum(case when to = 'A' then weight else 0 end) as a,
       sum(case when to = 'B' then weight else 0 end) as b,
       sum(case when to = 'C' then weight else 0 end) as c,
       sum(case when to = 'D' then weight else 0 end) as d,
       sum(case when to = 'E' then weight else 0 end) as d
from (select 'A' as col1 union all select 'B' union all select 'C' union all select 'D' union all select 'E'
     ) c left join
     t
     on t.from = c.col1
group by c.col1;
```

If you don't know the original columns, you could combine the values into a single string:

```
select col1.col, 
       group_concat(col2.col, ':', t.weight order by col2.col)
from ((select `from` as col from t
      ) union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select `to` from t
      )
     ) col1 cross join
     ((select `from` as col from t
      ) union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select `to` from t
      )
     ) col2 left join
     t
     on col1.col = t.`from` and col2.col = t.`from`
group by col1.col;
```

If you actually want separate columns and don't know the values, then you would need dynamic SQL.